# How do I connect Databricks to a local postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, databricks

I am trying to connect a local postgresql database to databricks to work through some tutorials. I continue to get the error below. Queries are working on both the CLI and PGADMIN.

I uploaded a the JDBC driver to the Databricks cluster, but am not having success connecting. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

database_host = "localhost"
database_port = "5432" # update if you use a non-default port
database_name = "pysparkdb"
table = "authors"
user = "postgres"
password = "*****"

url = f"jdbc:postgresql://{database_host}:{database_port}/{database_name}"

remote_table = (spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", driver)
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", table)
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", password)
  .load()
)
```

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Comment: What is the CLI which is working?

Comment: I am just using terminal, but I am able to connect in Jupyter Notebooks using psycopg2. The issue appears to be between databricks and the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Local means "local to something" - in your case it's your laptop or desktop.
Databricks clusters are running in one of the clouds (AWS/Azure/GCP) so they don't have any knowledge about what you're running locally. And when you're specifying `localhost` as host name, it's resolved to the machine where Spark is running (`127.0.0.1`), and of course it doesn't have any PostgreSQL instance running.

To connect to your database you need to provide a possibility to reach it via VPN, or something like that.  For example, on Azure you can follow [these instructions to setup connection to on-premise services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network).  Or people are using some cloud-specific database, like, RDS on AWS, etc.