# Can't connect to on premise SQL Server with jdbc

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, jdbc, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I'm trying to connect to my local server from databricks(community edition), but I get this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
> to the host 127.0.0.1, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection
> refused (Connection refused). Verify the connection properties. Make
> sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and
> accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP
> connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

I tried the recommendations from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed)

I enabled and set the TCP to 1433 and restarted the server, further enabled the IP address and check the connection to the port with telnet

[image]
[image]

this is the first code

```
table = (spark.read
  .format("sqlserver")
  .option("host", '127.0.0.1')
  .option("port", "1433") 
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", passw)
  .option("database", "TestDatabase")
  .option("dbtable", "dbo.table1")
  .load()
)
```

and the second

```
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;database=TestDatabase"#jdbc:sqlserver://{database_host}:{database_port};database={database_name}

table = (spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", driver)
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", "dbo.table1")
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", password)
  .load()
)
```

In both cases I get the same error, for the host name I tried '127.0.0.1','localhost' and 'DESKTOP-N1VTIO2'

Comment: Databricks Community Edition is a cloud-based micro-cluster solution hosted by AWS. Ref: [Databricks CE FAQ](https://www.databricks.com/product/faq/community-edition). How will it connect to your own machine on `localhost [127.0.0.1]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect Databricks to a local postgresql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75563160/how-do-i-connect-databricks-to-a-local-postgresql-database)